# get information devices registered users GCM

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am using Node.js to push information to the device manually through registrationIds  is removed from the device client. But I do not know how to get the information directly from the server registrationIds GCM without having to enter manually when I want to send a message to the client.

Example: I want to replace ***APA91bHg7QEO3h44OCrBAb6yoHEvNvVSrRRcJjufS5fduCw2YhC83BZ9eqlxYS9PbKIAoFrmK-rvNEQ-CxrAjy4Wy13CRt5or1h7kG9XDRg2Tcy4zx8EpGOYLybmgnLDmVVvTJF4PR9Y*** with an id is taken directly from the GCM.

Code server:

```
var gcm = require('node-gcm');
//var gcm = require('../gcm.js');

var message = new gcm.Message();
var sender = new gcm.Sender('AIzaSyB8IAgyo9DJbmGiVISnCCoxcQRD7em6KfI');
var registrationIds = [];

message.addData('title','Long Van');
message.addData('message','Ket qua xo so moi nhat!!!!');
message.addData('msgcnt','1');
message.collapseKey = 'demo';
message.delayWhileIdle = true;
message.timeToLive = 3;

// At least one token is required - each app registers a different token
 registrationIds.push('APA91bHg7QEO3h44OCrBAb6yoHEvNvVSrRRcJjufS5fduCw2YhC83BZ9eqlxYS9PbKIAoFrmK-rvNEQ-CxrAjy4Wy13CRt5or1h7kG9XDRg2Tcy4zx8EpGOYLybmgnLDmVVvTJF4PR9Y');

/**
 * Parameters: message-literal, registrationIds-array, No. of retries, callback-function
 */

sender.send(message, registrationIds, 4, function (result) {
console.log(result);
});
/** Use the following line if you want to send the message without retries
sender.sendNoRetry(message, registrationIds, function (result) {
console.log(result); });
**/
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is when the device register with GCM, GCM will return back the token ID / reg ID (whatever you call it) and at this time, you should update your server with this ID along with some additional info to identify the ID (maybe en associated email or username?)